# javascript property checking to prevent application break

Tags: javascript

I face this issue so many time, dealing with nested object.

```
this.props.something.something2
```

Above statement is dangerious, it can took my entire application, simply because I didn't aware of this.props.something can be optional. How to do checking in such case?

Answer (score 0):

Before accessing to 'something2' of this.props.something, you should check the existing of 'something' first.

```
if(this.props.something) {
   alert(this.props.something.something2);
 }
```